# Stop Rails from trying to provide a template / ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, controller, respond-with

I have a simple angular rails app that I am trying to get wired up.

Here is my rails controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def index
    @items = Item.order(params[:sort]).page(params[:page]).per(15)
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.where(params[:id])

    if @item.empty?
      flash[:alert] = "Item number #{params[:id]} does not exist"
    else
      respond_with @item do |format|
        format.json { render :layout => false }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting the `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error because rails keeps trying to serve up an erb template. I don't want a template!! I just want json. Can some one please give the definitive respond_to/respond_with syntax that will rid me of templates forever?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there are two ways in rails for rendering, CMIIW

first, as default, it will render a view template, example

```
  def show
  end
```

then it will render default show view template, example: app/views/controller_name/show.html.erb

second is by manual render, use `render` method

if you want to respond to json only, then:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    id = params.require(:id)
    @item = Item.find_by(id: id)

    if @item.nil?
      render json: { message: "Item number #{id} does not exist", status: :not_found }
    else
      render json: @item
    end
  end
end
```

no need to use `respond_to`, and it's been removed from newest rails too

rails guide about `render` is really useful, you can read it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

Comment: Just a note: I believe ```render json: @item.to_json``` can be ```render json: @item``` with Active Record Serializer.